# Direct2D and custom shaped window

Tags: directx, transparent, direct2d

Does Direct2D support custom shaped windows? Say, drawing a circle over all other windows. If yes, could anyone give a link to an article or sample of such technique? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yep, it does.
2. Here is an article with examples, unfortunately, it goes in Russian, so use an online translator:

http://teran.karelia.pro/articles/item_5710.html